# for_each on a resource with count on other resource

Tags: terraform

I am trying to do this :

Add or not repo if set or not :

```
resource "google_cloudbuildv2_repository" "repo" {
  count             = var.repo != "" ? 1 : 0
}
```

do a for_each on an other variable (list) , but repo.id is required and so having a count and for_each doesn't work well

```
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "tf_plan" {
  for_each        = toset(var.tf_dir)

  repository_event_config {
    repository = google_cloudbuildv2_repository.repo.id
    pull_request {
      branch = "^main$"
    }
  }
```

I have try something like that :

```
for_each = var.repo != "" ? toset([var.tf_dir]) : toset([])
```

But not working.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The desired behaviour is not clear in the case where the repo isn’t created. Something like this should work regardless of what happens with the `count`, you can substitute "" with the id of an existing repository, or even a variation of what the var.repo value is:

```
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "tf_plan" {
  for_each        = toset(var.tf_dir)

  repository_event_config {
    repository = var.repo != "" ? google_cloudbuildv2_repository.repo.id : "<default-repo>"
    pull_request {
    branch = "^main$"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it w/

```
for_each = var.repo != "" ? toset([var.tf_dir]) : toset([])
```

You just had an extra set of brackets around `var.tf_dir`, which is already a list. This should work

```
for_each = var.repo != "" ? toset(var.tf_dir) : toset([])
```

but if the trigger directly depends on the repository, you could instead use the trigger repository resource as your `for_each` argument. The trigger will not be created if the repository is not created.

```
resource "google_cloudbuildv2_repository" "repo" {
  count             = var.repo != "" ? 1 : 0
} 

resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "tf_plan" {
  for_each        = google_cloudbuildv2_repository.repo

  repository_event_config {
    repository = each.value.id
    pull_request {
      branch = "^main$"
    }
  }
}
```